drizzle-kit not able to find dirzzle-orm on cli
I'm using yarn workspaces to structure a monorepo style project. I recently upgraded to yarn v4 and am running into issues with running drizzle-kit seemingly not able to detect drizzle-rom when run from the cli now.
When I run
yarn drizzle-kit generate --name foo

I get the error:
/Users/anthony/dev/theproject/.pnp.cjs:13083
      Error.captureStackTrace(firstError);
            ^

Error: drizzle-kit tried to access drizzle-orm, but it isn't declared in its dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

Required package: drizzle-orm (via "drizzle-orm/casing")
Required by: drizzle-kit@npm:0.26.2 (via /Users/anthony/.yarn/berry/cache/drizzle-kit-npm-0.26.2-c249bdc6e1-10c0.zip/node_modules/drizzle-kit/)

Require stack:
- /Users/anthony/.yarn/berry/cache/drizzle-kit-npm-0.26.2-c249bdc6e1-10c0.zip/node_modules/drizzle-kit/bin.cjs
    at require$$0.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/anthony/dev/theproject/.pnp.cjs:13083:13)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:27)
    at require$$0.Module._load (/Users/anthony/dev/theproject/.pnp.cjs:12974:31)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:217:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1339:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:126:16)
    at src/utils.ts (/Users/anthony/.yarn/berry/cache/drizzle-kit-npm-0.26.2-c249bdc6e1-10c0.zip/node_modules/drizzle-kit/bin.cjs:6775:21)
    at __init (/Users/anthony/.yarn/berry/cache/drizzle-kit-npm-0.26.2-c249bdc6e1-10c0.zip/node_modules/drizzle-kit/bin.cjs:10:56)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/anthony/.yarn/berry/cache/drizzle-kit-npm-0.26.2-c249bdc6e1-10c0.zip/node_modules/drizzle-kit/bin.cjs:85751:1)

Here is my package.json (other dependencies truncated
{
  "name": "@myproject/users-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.35.1",
    . . .
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.26.2",
    . . .
  },
  . . .
}

This is my .yarnrc.yml from the root of the project
nodeLinker: pnp

If I add drizzle-kit and drizzle-orm to the root of the project I can successfully run drizzle-kit with:
yarn workspace @myproject/users-api db:generate foo

Additionally, if I switch to using a node-modules nodeLinker strategy running drizzle-kit succeeds
nodeLinker: node-modules

Am I missing a needed configuration?
